Using smithy aws client library fails with Region is missing
I am using the AWS S3 client with the following AWS libraries in my package.json
@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.540.0",
"@smithy/node-http-handler": "^2.5.0"
I created the S3 Client properties specifying them like this:
            getAgent(): Agent {
                 const agent = new Agent({
                        rejectUnauthorized: true,
                      });
                return agent;
            } 


           async getClient (): Promise<S3Client> {
               const agent = this.getAgent()
               const endPoint: EndpointV2  = {url: new URL('url')} as EndpointV2 
               const s3Config = {
                region: 'us-west-2',
                endpoint: endPoint,
                credentials: {
                  accessKeyId: 'myKey' ,
                  secretAccessKey: 'mySecret'
                },
               requestHandler:new NodeHttpHandler({
                  httpAgent: agent,
                  httpsAgent: agent
               }),
               retryStrategy: new ConfiguredRetryStrategy(
                   13, 3000
               )
              } 
              const client = new S3Client([s3Config]);
              return client
          }



However, when I instantiate the client I get the following error
Error is Error: Region is missing
at default (/home/app/src/node_modules/@smithy/config-resolver/dist-cjs/index.js:117:11)
at /home/app/src/node_modules/@smithy/node-config-provider/dist-cjs/index.js:72:104
at /home/app/src/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/index.js:79:33
at async coalesceProvider (/home/app/src/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/index.js:106:18)
at async /home/app/src/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/index.js:117:20
at async region (/home/app/src/node_modules/@smithy/config-resolver/dist-cjs/index.js:142:30)
at async /home/app/src/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:89:28
at async /home/app/src/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:120:14
at async /home/app/src/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/index.js:33:22
The region is clearly present. This error only started when I updated my application to use the smithy library since the previous library has been deprecated. Please help in resolving this

My mistake, I am passing the properties in an array, when creating the client
It should be created like this
 const client = new S3Client(s3Config);
 instead of
 
 const client = new S3Client([s3Config]);


 

